# MATLAB: Efficient way to find a goal value based on two variables

Tags: matlab, optimization, binary-tree, solver

I have a system from which I need to attain a defined goal `G` from a starting value `G0` by adjusting two actuators `A` and `B`  with initial values `A0` and `B0` whose values vary dependently i.e. if I adjust `A`, `B` will change slightly but needs to be kept constant at `B0`.

To attain `G` I need to move `A` from `-pos` to `+pos` in steps of 1 and after each step, check if `abs(G-G0) <2` and also check if `B` has deviated from `B0` i.e. `abs(B-B0)<2`. If it has I need to adjust its position in the range `-pos1` to `+pos1` in steps of 1 until  `B=B0`.
The iteration stops when I find a value of A which satisfies `G` (`G=80` in my example below).

At the moment I am using a for loop:

Let's suppose

```
    G=80;  
G0=73;
pos0=50;
pos=5;
pos1=7;

for posA=-pos+pos0:1:pos0+pos
    
    A=moveA(posA);   %moveA represents the transfer function that takes posA and moves actuator A, returning value A
    
    
    if abs(G-G0)>2 && abs(B-B0)> 2
        for posB=-pos+pos1:1:pos1+pos
            B=moveB(posB);   %moveB represents the transfer function that takes posB and moves actuator B, returning value B
            if abs(B-B0)> 2
                break;
            else
                continue
            end
        end
    else
        fprintf('  %i is the value of A to reach goal',A)
        break
    end
end
```

I'm looking for suggestions to optimize and speed up this code in MATLAB, as currently it takes a long time iterating.

Comment: Have you tried to profile your code? If not, then it can show you where the bottlenecks are.

Comment: I guess the bottleneck is in the functions `moveB()` and `moveA()`. The other operations you are doing are very simple and should not take a lot of time. An other possibility is that you run a lot of iterations. Can you tell us how many MATLAB is doing?

Comment: @NickyMattsson I have and the bottleneck is in the move functions

Comment: @ChristianYami you are right - the move functions take the most time. Sometimes the goal is reached within less than 5 iterations and other times it takes much longer (up to the last index of the iteration)

Comment: Is it me who needs glasses, or are the `moveA` and `moveB` functions not defined? making it a bit hard to help.

Comment: @NickyMattsson they are functions that send the position data to move stepper motors. I think it's not relevant to step into them.

Comment: @Buzz how could they not be relevant for optimization of the code if they are the only slow thing? The other option is that you learn about non-linear optimizaton instead of bruteforcing the problem.

Comment: @AnderBiguri there is nothing I can do to change the hardware. The functions just send the position commands as a string over a serial port.